# Solving equation equal to zero

Tags: python, sympy

How I can equate an equation to zero then solve it (the purpose is to eliminate the denominator).

```
y=(x**2-2)/3*x
```

In Matlab this works:

`solution= solve(y==0,x)`

but not in python.

Comment: What do you mean by **equate an equation to zero then solve it**?

Comment: Are you trying to solve this with Sympy specifically? You have tagged the question with `sympy`

Comment: Yes with sympy. But it can be any other methods. I want to take the derivative and then equate the result to zero to eliminate denominator.

Comment: The default is that if you solve an expression without an equation, it will be set equal to 0 so you can simply do `solve(y)` or `solve(y, x)` to specify solving for x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want only to eliminate the denominator, then you can split it into numerator and denominator. If the equation is already appear as a fraction and you want the numerator then

```
>>> y=(x**2-2)/(3*x); y  # note parentheses around denom, is that what you meant?
(x**2 - 2)/(3*x)
>>> numer(_)
x**2 - 2
```

But if the equation appears as a sum then you can put it over a denominator and perhaps factor to identify numerator factors that must be zero in order to solve the equation:

```
>>> y + x/(x**2+2)
x/(x**2 + 2) + (x**2 - 2)/(3*x)
>>> n, d = _.as_numer_denom(); (n, d)
(3*x**2 + (x**2 - 2)*(x**2 + 2), 3*x*(x**2 + 2))
>>> factor(n)
(x - 1)*(x + 1)*(x**2 + 4)
>>> solve(_)
[-1, 1, -2*I, 2*I]
```

You don't have to factor the numerator before attempting to solve, however. But I sometimes find it useful when working with a specific equation.

If you have an example of an equation that is solved quickly elsewhere but not in SymPy, please post it.

Answer (score 3):

```
from sympy import *

x, y = symbols('x y') 

y=(x**2-2)/3*x

# set the expression, y, equal to 0 and solve
result = solve(Eq(y, 0))

print(result)
```

Another solution:

```
from sympy import *

x, y = symbols('x y')

equation = Eq(y, (x**2-2)/3*x)

# Use sympy.subs() method
result = solve(equation.subs(y, 0))

print(result)
```

Edit (even simpler):

```
from sympy import *

x, y = symbols('x y') 

y=(x**2-2)/3*x

# solve the expression y (by default set equal to 0)
result = solve(y)

print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks!! :)the second solution is better BUT when the equation becomes complicated and has multi variable, sympy is not able to solve it :/ while symbolic toolbox in Matlab doesn't have problem with anything. I don't know maybe python has special tricks.